# Injecting attribute and value from var

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I'm trying to inject an attribute and it's value based on a cookie and a variable list.

The cookie has a numeric value and is being set without problems:

```
function setCookie(key, value) {
    var expires = new Date();
    expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    document.cookie = key + '=' + value + ';expires=' + expires.toUTCString();
}

function getCookie(key) {
    var keyValue = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + key + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
    return keyValue ? keyValue[2] : null;
}
```

Now I have a list of text that should change dynamically depending on the cookie value.

```
var myDynamicTexs = {
    1: "AAAA",
    2: "BBBB",
    3: "CCCC",
}
```

I need to grab the text based on the cookie numeric value. I'm able to get the cookie value by using:

```
var myText = getCookie('myCookie')
```

But I don't seem to be able make the text belonging to the number of the cookie value visible anywhere.

I need the text values for 2 purposes:

1) To show them as text visible in the website:

```
$('#myelement1').html('code to grab the text')
```

This would have the effect that if the cookie value is 1, #myelement1 would print:

```
<p id='myelement1'>AAAA</p>
```

2) To use them as the value for element attributes:

```
$('div')attr.('id','code to grab the text')
```

If the cookie value is 2, `<div>` would become: `<div class="BBBB">`

I tried the below but din't work:

```
$('div').attr('class', myDynamicTexs[(getCookie('myCookie'))]);
```

It needs to be JavaScript or JQuery as I cannot modify the original HTML template.

Any hint?

Comment: 2 - you want to apply the same `id` to all `div`s in the DOM?

Comment: @jkris No, that was just an example. I didn't want to make the question too long. It be for `class` or `name`.

Comment: Are you sure you can change a dom-elements id?

Comment: @fast it would be to add the value of the attribute in general. `id` was a bad example. It would be to add values `class`and `name` etc.

Comment: Using myDynamicTexs[(getCookie('myCookie'))] as your 'code to grab the text' looks ok..

Comment: The line: $('.post-tag').attr("data-test", myDynamicTexs[(getCookie('my'))])  works well here... using your setCookie, getCookie

Comment: The code you show is correct, the problem must be anywhere else!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('div').attr('class', myDynamicTexs[**(**getCookie('myCookie')**)**]);
```

Won't it be

```
$('div').attr('class', myDynamicTexs[getCookie('myCookie')]);
```

as myDynamicTexs is an array?

Comment: The extra () do not any harm

Comment: Sure, but it doesn't change the result of the code.

Comment: those two lines are identical, wrapping the getCookie call in parenthesis will not change the returned value. So if the getCookie call returns `"AAAA"` both lines would still be evaluated as `myDynamicTexs["AAAA"]`. Also `myDynamicTexs` is an object not an array

Comment: If you want to add a class, use $('element').addClass(myDynamicTexs[getCookie('myCookie')]) instead of $('element').attr('class', 'newClass')